# How do I set an upper bound on Gradle dynamic versions?

Tags: gradle, versioning, dependency-management

I can't find any explicit documentation on Gradle dynamic version syntax -- the examples in the [official docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) are `1.+` and `2.+`, neither of which appears to have an upper bound.

Say I have `1.0-SNAPSHOT` and `2.0-SNAPSHOT` in my repository, and I want a certain project to pull in the first **or** any future stable `1.x`, but not the second.

I've tried both [Maven syntax](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) (`[1.0,2.0)`) and [Ivy syntax](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html) (`[1.0,2.0[`). Both of these pull in `2.0-SNAPSHOT`. Why? Is `2.0-SNAPSHOT` considered "less than" `2.0`?

On that assumption, I tried the obvious hacks: `[1.0,2.0-SNAPSHOT)` and `[1.0,2.0-SNAPSHOT[`, but both of those just fail dependency resolution.

How can I tell Gradle I only want version `1.x`?

Comment: What do you mean by "1.+ does not have an upper bound"? 2.0 is an upper bound, as is 2.0-something. Yes, 2.0-something is considered less than 2.0.

Comment: How does "1.+" express the upper bound "2.0"?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean *least* upper bound?

Comment: Does "1+" not mean ">=1"?

Comment: `1.+` means "highest version starting with `1.`".

Comment: Good to know. Is that documented anywhere? As far as I can tell it's just used without explanation in chapters [8](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) and [50](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) of the Gradle docs. And is there a syntax that lets one express `1 <= version < 3.0-SNAPSHOT`, i.e. "any version 1 or 2, but not even the snapshot of 3"?

Comment: I'm not aware of any docs. Syntax is the same as supported by Ivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is that `+` includes an implicit upper bound. So `1.+` means "any version that starts with `1.`"

This doesn't seem to be anywhere in the Gradle docs, but it is documented for [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html):

> - end the revision with a +
>     selects the latest sub-revision of the dependency module. For instance, 
>     if the dependency module exists in revision 1.0.3, 1.0.7 and 1.1.2, "1.0.+" will select 1.0.7.