# How does gradle evaluate dynamic dependencies?

Tags: gradle

The Gradle documentation is very sparse on how dynamic dependencies are resolved.

There are two styles of dynamic dependency declaration: `lib:20.+` and `lib:20.0+`.

Are they equivalent?

Do `20.1` , `21` and `20.0.1` match these declarations?

Typically, I want to get fixes (x.y versions with x fixed) automatically and manually update to the next major version which can include breaking changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set an upper bound on Gradle dynamic versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203796/how-do-i-set-an-upper-bound-on-gradle-dynamic-versions)

Comment: Syntax and semantics are the same as used by Ivy.

Comment: @blgt thanks, but it lacks an explanation on the second style '1.1+'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found an answer, in the Ivy documentation of all places  :

Revision    Matches
1.0.+   all revisions starting with '1.0.', like 1.0.1, 1.0.5, 1.0.a
1.1+    all revisions starting with '1.1', like 1.1, 1.1.5, but also 1.10, 1.11

source : http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html